# Validar cabecera excel antes de comenzar a importar( Laravel excel)

Tags: php, laravel, excel, laravel-excel

favor me ayudan con lo siguiente, estoy realizando la importación de una planilla excel, con el paquete [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/)  y mi código funciona sin problemas, logre realizar la lectura e importación del documento, pero me toca realizar la validación de este, ya que cuando se sube el archivo de excel con el formato correspondiente pasa, pero cuando se sube un documento con otro formato este pasa igual, no realiza la importación, pero tampoco da aviso de que el formato no corresponde.

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente

public function prestoImport(Request $request)

```
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    Excel::import(new PrestoImport, $file);
}
```

y en mi archivo PrestoImport.php tengo lo siguiente

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        // .... lectura e inserción de los datos
    }
}
```

No logro entender donde tendría que ir el código de para validar la cabecera del excel que debe contener las columnas Código, Nat, Ud y Resumen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu modelo debe de implementar la interfaz `WithValidation`, así que tendrías algo como:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class PrestoImport implements ToModel, WithValidation{
   //...
}
```

Para validar los encabezados, suponiendo que esperas que el encabezado siempre esté en la primera fila, dentro de tu archivo `PrestoImport.php`, sería algo como:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [

         // Siempre valida por lotes
         // Fila.columna
         '0.0' => 'in:Código',
         '0.1' => 'in:Nat',
         '0.2' => 'in:Ud',
         '0.3' => 'in:Resumen',

    ];
}
```

Si no estás en PHP 7 o superior, solo elimina el tipo de dato esperado de retorno:

```
public function rules(){
   //...
}
```

Para atrapar la excepción que generará, hay varias formas, una de ellas es encerrar el código de importación en un `try` `catch`.

```
try {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    Excel::import(new PrestoImport, $file);
} catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
     $fallas = $e->failures();

     foreach ($fallas as $falla) {
         $falla->row(); // fila en la que ocurrió el error
         $falla->attribute(); // el número de columna o la "llave" de la columna
         $falla->errors(); // Errores de las validaciones de laravel
         $falla->values(); // Valores de la fila en la que ocurrió el error.
     }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias compañero, es justamente lo que estaba buscando